# How to convert any non-negative matrix into a doubly stochastic matrix?

Tags: matrices, stochastic-matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Given a non-negative real matrix $A \in \Bbb R_+^{m \times n}$, how do I convert it to a doubly stochastic matrix (each row and column sums to $1$)

$$\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}= 1, \qquad \forall i = 1, \dots, m \tag{row sum}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^m A_{ij}= 1, \qquad \forall j = 1, \dots, n \tag{column sum}$$

Is the conversion possible? If not, can we find a nearest matrix that is doubly stochastic matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"?  What should be the relationship between the original matrix and the new one?

Comment: @NateEldredge by convert i mean $f(A)$ should result in doubly stochastic matrix

Comment: Note that it is impossible for all the row sums and all the column sums to be 1 if the matrix is not square.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you know any reference where it has been proved. I guess proof must be very much simple

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did my best to prove the same. consider a rectangular matrix $A$ with dimension $m \times n$. Sum of row sums will be $m$ where as sum of column sums will be $n$. However we added all the entries in the matrix once which does not give rise to two numbers. Hence there wont be a rectangular matrix which is doubly stochastic.

Comment: You got it, Learner.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Please don't make purely cosmetic edits to (ten year) old posts. It puts them on the active queue, where they distract from new postings.

Comment: @EthanBolker Adding tags is not a purely cosmetic edit.  It is how one can find duplicates and prevent answering the same questions over and over again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a paper by Richard Sinkhorn: *A relationship between arbitrary positive matrices and doubly stochastic matrices*, The Annals of Mathematical statistics, 35 (1964), 876–879.

There he proves the following

**Theorem.** If $A$ is a square matrix with *strictly positive* entries then there are a unique doubly stochastic matrix $T_A$ and diagonal matrices $D_1$, $D_2$ such that $T_A=D_1AD_2$. The matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ are themselves unique up to a scalar factor.

Comment: Thanks for your reference. Anything similar on rectangular matrix?

Comment: A non-square matrix cannot be doubly stochastic. A doubly stochastic matrix $T$ should be able to define transition probability forward and backward $T^\top$ in time. If this matrix is not square, it means that in one of these directions some states are not used. Either there is an absorbing subspace forward in time, or there is a an absorbing subspace in the time-reversed process. In any case $\mathbb 1$ cannot be either a left or right eigenvector.