# Sinkhorn theorem for doubly stochastic matrices

Tags: matrices, stochastic-matrices

I was reading something about doubly stochastic matrices and got stuck while reading the original proof of the uniqueness part of the [Sinkhorn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinkhorn%27s_theorem). I'm not able to understand the logic. Could someone help me in figuring it out? I state below the theorem and the proof as written in the original paper.

---

**Theorem:** To a given strictly positive $N \times N$ matrix $A$ corresponds exactly one doubly stochastic matrix $T=D_1AD_2$ where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are diagonal matrices with positive diagonals. The matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ are themselves unique up to a scalar factor.

---

**Uniqueness proof:** if there exist two different pairs of diagonal matrices $C_1, C_2$ and $D_1, D_2$ such that both $C_1 A C_2$ and $D_1 A D_2$ are doubly stochastic, then this means that there exist a positive doubly stochastic matrix $P$ and matrices

$$B_1 = \mbox{diag}[b_{11}, b_{12},\dots, b_{1N}]$$

and

$$B_2 = \mbox{diag}[b_{21}, b_{22}, \dots, b_{2N}]$$

which are not multiple of identity matrix, for which $B_1 P B_2$ is also doubly stochastic. But this is impossible since by convexity one obtains:

$$\min_jb_{2j} \le \frac{1}{b_{1i}} \le \max_j b_{2j}$$

and

$$\min_ib_{1j}\le \frac{1}{b_{2j}} \le \max_jb_{1i}$$

which leads to a contradiction if $b_{1i} b_{2j} \ne 1$ for some $i$ and $j$. It follows that $C_1 = p D_1$, $C_2 = p^{-1} D_2$ for some $p > 0$.

---

**What I do not understand:** why from the existence of $C_1,C_2$ and $D_1,D_2$ it will exist $P$, $B_1$ and $B_2$? What is the convexity argument? And why there is a contradiction? And how does it imply the thesis?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/179940/339790

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, the author means $P=D_1AD_2,\ B_1=C_1D_1^{-1},\ B_2=D_2^{-1}C_2$.

I'm not sure what he/she exactly meant by "convexity", but here is an alternative proof. Let $b_{1i_1} = \min_i b_{1i}$ and $b_{2j_2} = \max_j b_{2j}$. Observe that the $(i,j)$-th entry of $B_1PB_2$ is $b_{1i}b_{2j}p_{ij}$. Since $B_1PB_2$ is **row stochastic**, it follows that $\sum_j b_{1i}b_{2j}p_{ij}=1$ and in turn $\sum_j b_{2j}p_{ij}=\frac1{b_{1i}}$ for every $i$. Therefore,
$$
b_{2j_2} = b_{2j_2}\sum_j p_{i_1j} \ge \sum_j b_{2j}p_{i_1j} = \frac1{b_{1i_1}}.\tag{1}
$$
By similar reasoning, if we consider the **column stochasticity** of $B_1PB_2$ instead, we get
$$
b_{1i_1} = b_{1i_1}\sum_i p_{ij_2} \le \sum_i b_{1i}p_{ij_2} = \frac1{b_{2j_2}}.\tag{2}
$$
Therefore $b_{1i_1}b_{2j_2}=1$ and equalities must hold in both $(1)$ and $(2)$. Consequently, all $b_{2j}$s are identical to each other and all $b_{1i}$s are equal. That is, $B_1,B_2$ are scalar multiples of the identity matrix (and in fact, $B_2=B_1^{-1}$). Since $B_1=C_1D_1^{-1}$ and $B_2=D_2^{-1}C_2$, it follows that $D_1,D_2$ are respectively scalar multiples of $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the answer. It gives me more insight even if I don't see your first sentence so clear. The author calls $T=D_1AD_2$, while P is a positive stochastic matrix that should exists by the fact that there exist $T=D_1AD_2$ and $R=C_1AC_2$ (why?). We have to show that $T=R$ and $Cs=Ds$ up to a scalar factor. $B_1PB_2$ is doubly stochastic but not necessary strictly positive as P (why?). It seems to me that you simplified a little bit the demonstration.

Comment: @user26945 You can use the fact that $B_2=B_1^{-1}$ to directly verify that $D_1AD_2=C_1AC_2$. Since $D_1,D_2$ are positive diagonal matrices and $A$ is entrywise positive, it follows that $D_1AD_2$ is positive. As to the existence of $P$ (or $D_1,D_2$), of course I haven't demonstrated it, because all your question asks is about the uniqueness part.

Comment: We are negating the thesis assuming that there exist $C_1,C_2$ and $D_1,D_2$ different but for which $P=D_1AD_2=C_1AC_2$. Thanks to your reply we can easily show that there exist at least one couple $B_1,B_2$ for which $B_1PB_2$ is doubly stochastic and $B_1B_2=I$. So we can write the following chain:  $B_1PB_2=B_1D_1AD_2B_2=B_1C_1AC_2B_2$, so $B_1D_1=B_1C_1$ and $D_2B_2=C_2B_2$ that means $D_1=pC_1$ and $D_2=(1/p)B_2$ contraddicting the negation of the hypothesis. So we have done. What I'm missing now is: we're assuming $P=D_1AD_2=C_1AC_2$, but why the negation is not $P=D_1AD_2$ $R=C_1AC_2$

Comment: Sorry, but I think the better way to show the result is: by negating the thesis we have $P=D_1AD_2$, $R=C_1AC_2$. So $A=D_1^{-1}PD_2^{-1}$ and $R=C_1D_1^{-1}PD_2^{-1}C_2$. So we can call $B_1=C_1D_1^{-1}$ and $B_2=D_2^{-1}C_2$ and because R is doubly stochastic, thanks to your demonstration we have $B_1B_2=I$ and after substituing the previous expressions we get $D_1=pC_1$ and $D_2=p^{-1}C_2$. This solve all my doubts and I can pass to the existence part of the theorem. Thanks again!

Comment: For anyone curious, the author of this paper says "by convexity" a few times to refer to the fact $\text{min} x_{i}\le \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}p_{i}\le \text{max}_{i}x_{i}$ when $\sum_{}^{}p_{i}x_{i}$ is a convex combination of $x_{i}$.  So I think that this solution is the same as what Sinkhorn had in mind in his paper.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P = (p_{ij})$ be a doubly stochastic matrix, and $C = (c_{ij})$ another matrix. Consider their Hadamard product $P\odot C=(p_{ij} c_{ij})$. We have

$$\sum_{j} p_{ij} c_{ij}\le \max_{j} c_{ij}$$ and so

$$\min_i (\sum_{j} p_{ij} c_{ij}) \le  \min_i \max_i c_{ij} $$

Similarly

$$\max_j \min_i c_{ij} \le \max_j (\sum_{i} p_{ij} c_{ij})$$

Now let's assume moreover that

$$\min_i (\sum_{j} p_{ij} c_{ij}) = \max_j (\sum_{i} p_{ij} c_{ij}) ( = s) $$

( in general, it is $\le$, since sum by rows equals sum by columns). This is equivalent to all the rows and all the columns of $(p_{ij} c_{ij})$ has the same sum $s$.  We conclude

$$\max_j \min_i c_{ij} \le s \le \min_i \max_j c_{ij}$$

Now the above inequality for the extremes is not a new one. However, let's assume moreover that

$$\max_j \min_i c_{ij}= \min_i \max_j c_{ij}$$

in other words, the matrix $(c_{ij})$ has a *saddle point* $(i_0, j_0)$ ( and also that all $p_{ij}\ne 0$, so $>0$). From the above we conclude thas the $i_0$ row and the $j_0$ column are constant ( $=s$).

Now we can prove uniqueness. Assume that $P$ is doubly stochastic with all entries $>0$, $C= (\alpha_i \cdot \beta_j)$, with $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i\ge 0$, and the matrix $P\odot C$ has all the row sums and column sums equal. Now the matrix $C$ has a saddle point (indeed, $\min_i \max_j \alpha_i \beta_j = \min_i \alpha_i \cdot \max_j \beta_j$), so $C$ has one constant row and one constant column. We conclude that all of the entries of $C$ are the same.