# Transform a rank-$N$ matrix to a double stochastic matrix without any iterative algorithms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonlinear-optimization, stochastic-matrices

Is there a way to take a general $N \times N$ matrix $Y$, and turn it into a [double stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) $X$ analytically?

1. With any iterative algorithms?

Ans: The Sinkhorn algorithm does that, but iteratively. One needs to alternatively normalize raws and columns for several iterations.

Richard Sinkhorn: A relationship between arbitrary positive matrices and doubly stochastic matrices, The Annals of Mathematical statistics, 35 (1964), 876–879.

**Theorem.** If $A$ is a square matrix with *strictly positive* entries then there are a unique doubly stochastic matrix $T_A$ and diagonal matrices $D_1$, $D_2$ such that $T_A=D_1AD_2$. The matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ are themselves unique up to a scalar factor.

See [How to convert any matrix to doubly stochastic matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/179940/79069)

2. Without any iterative algorithms?